# How to open link to ePub file in iBooks, when link is in UIWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview, epub

Links to ePub files automatically offer user option to load in iBooks--when the link is accessed from Safari.

However, I have an app with an UIWebView that links to an ePub file. I want to give the user the same option: let the link open in iBooks. However, that option is never given. When the link is tapped, the activity indicator spins for a few seconds, stops, and that's it.

To be clear so that no one flags this as a duplicate question: I do not want to open the epub file within the UIWebView or within the app at all for that matter. I just want the link to open (or give the user the option to open) the file in ibooks.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's any way to control that, you have to use what the phone let you open.

Comment: I'm afraid you're right. I'll wait a bit longer to see if anyone else can present anything, otherwise I'll mark yours as the answer. Thanks.